# Beginner: linear system with parameter - how to solve with gaussian elimination?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$\begin{cases}x-ty  = 1\\(t-1)x -2y = 1\end{cases} x,y,t \in \mathbb{R} $

So the corresponding matrix is
$\begin{bmatrix}1 & -t & 1 \\t-1 & -2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$

I know by equaling (I) and (II) and substituting (where one has to divide by $t-2$ and $-1-t$) that for $t=2$ and $t=-1$ the system has no (unique) solution.

Now I want to solve the system by gaussian elimination and get a general answer for x,y dependent on t.
Problem: If I want to eliminate an coefficient, I need to multiply (I) by $t-1$ where $t\neq 1$ or (II) by $t$ where $t\neq0$.
But this adds an "extra case" because multiplying by $0$ is not allowed and my general solutions will not work only for this specific choice of $t$.

Can somebody just tell me, what i need to do in order to achieve general solutions with no special case for t by gaussian elimination ? Or am I just getting something wrong ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

We'll perform Gaussian elimination on the augmented matrix:

\begin{align}
&\begin{bmatrix}
1&-t&1\\
t-1&-2&1
\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
1&-t&1\\
0&t^2-t-2&2-t
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&-t&1\\
0&(t+1)(t-2)&2-t
\end{bmatrix} \\[1ex]
\text{If $t=-1\phantom{,2}$}\qquad
 \phantom{A}= {}
&\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1\\
0&0&3
\end{bmatrix}:\quad\text{the linear system is inconsistent.} \\[1ex]
\text{If $t=2:\phantom{-}$}\qquad
 \phantom{A}= {}
&\begin{bmatrix}
1&-2&1\\
0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}:\quad\text{the linear system has a set of solutions of codimension $1$.} \\
\text{If $t\ne-1,2:$}\qquad\rightsquigarrow &\begin{bmatrix}
1&-t&1\\
0&1&-\dfrac 1{t+1}
\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&\dfrac 1{t+1}\\
0&1&-\dfrac 1{t+1}
\end{bmatrix}:\enspace\text{the linear system has a unique  solution.}
\end{align}

Comment: thanks, i did not see it this way, but my mathematical mind got expanded again !

Answer (score 0):

From the first equation we get
$$x=1+ty$$ so we get with the second equation 
$$(t-1)(1+ty)-2y=1$$

$$y(t^2-t-2)=2-t$$

Can you finish?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have gotten a bit confused about the “don’t multiply by zero” rule. Now, it’s certainly true that you never want to erase a row by multiplying it by zero, but an elementary row operation like $R_2\to R_2-(t-1)R_1$ is perfectly legitimate. If $t=1$, this becomes $R_2\to R_2-0R_1$, which just leaves $R_2$ unchanged. The second row of the original matrix has a leading zero when $t=1$, which is what we were trying to produce with that row operation, anyway.

On the other hand, you do have to be very careful about *dividing* by zero, which will come up later in the process of computing the RREF of your matrix. That will require a case analysis (see [Bernard’s answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2953088/265466)).